# Как вывести имя месяца на русском

Tags: javascript

Пробовал так

`new Date(2020, 11).toLocaleString('ru', {month: 'long' })` получаю Декабрь

Пробовал так

```
this.monthNames[new Date(this.year, this.month).getMonth() - 1]

monthNames: [
                    "Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь",
                    "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"
                ],
```

Но таким образом все месяца выводятся кроме Декабря

Comment: `getMonth()` возвращает число от 0 до 11. 0 - январь, 1 - февраль ... 11 - декабрь. Таким образом правильно будет `this.monthNames[new Date(this.year, this.month).getMonth()]` где `this.month` так же от 0(январь) до 11(декабрь)

Answer (score 3):

Вычитайте 1 из нужного месяца. В js месяца начинаются с 0, т.е. январь - нулевой месяц, а декабрь - 11